ROS2 Error while installing dependencies (rosdep)
I successfully compiled and installed ROS2 on Arch Linux. Everything is working fine (surprisingly!). As I initialized rosdep I got this error:
➜  ~ sudo rosdep init
[sudo] password di enf: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rosdep", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('rosdep==0.22.2', 'console_scripts', 'rosdep')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/rosdep", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 202, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1126, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rosdep2/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .installers import InstallerContext, Installer, \
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rosdep2/installers.py", line 36, in <module>
    from rospkg.os_detect import OsDetect
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rospkg/os_detect.py", line 42, in <module>
    import distro
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distro'

Under any circumstance, installing the pip module distro would have been enough:
pip install distro --break-system-packages
As a proof I ran:
➜  ~ python                     
Python 3.11.8 (main, Feb 12 2024, 14:50:05) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import distro
>>> 

which gave me no error, and also:
➜  ~ pip list | grep distro
distro                               1.9.0
rosdistro                            0.9.0

Can anybody help me finding out what the error is?
Thanks for reading

I fixed that issue by modifying the file /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rospkg/os_detect.py, by importing platform as distro, i.e. the new imports of that file became:
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function

import codecs
# to be removed after Ubuntu Xenial is out of support
import sys
# if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
#     import distro
# else:
#     import platform as distro
import platform as distro
import locale
import os
import platform
import subprocess

Then I got this new error
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rosdep2/lookup.py", line 33, in <module>
    import yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'

and then many similar issues and solved them by installing the dependencies manually:
paru -S python-yaml python-jaraco.text python-jaraco.functools python-jaraco.context python-more-itertools python-platformdirs python-packaging python-distro python-dateutil python-validate-pyproject python-tomli python-ordered-set python-six python-fastjsonschema python-autocommand python-typing-extensions
... and it finally worked!
